Rich kid gets slapped by a former servant of his house
His family was bankrupt, dead, or something along the same lines.
In this scene his former servants where removing all the furniture from his house, and he was standing there, all alone, in a bare house and shouting at them to obey his commands and stop looting the house.
It was noticeable that he was used to them always doing what he says before, so he continued shouting at them thinking that they’ll eventually comply. Then, however, one of the workers finally stopped ignoring him, approached him and then slapped him, and he (the child) was really shocked by this outcome.
It was probably a film about war, revolution or something like that, but all I remember is that scene and that there were strong air currents moving through the house, since many of the doors and windows were wide open.
The film should be at least ~15 years old.

Possibly Steven Spielberg's Empire of the Sun with Christian Bale and John Malkovich from 1987:

Based on J. G. Ballard's autobiographical novel, tells the story of a boy, James Graham, whose privileged life is upturned by the Japanese invasion of Shanghai, December 8, 1941. Separated from his parents, he is eventually captured, and taken to Soo Chow confinement camp, next to a captured Chinese airfield. Amidst the sickness and food shortages in the camp, Jim attempts to reconstruct his former life, all the while bringing spirit and dignity to those around him.

In one scene:

Jamie arrives home to find the house empty. He sees signs of a struggle in his parents bedroom, perhaps indicating that his mother was taken from the house by force. He hears noise downstairs and finds the maid of the house with the other Chinese servant, stealing furniture. When Jamie demands to know what they're doing, the former calmly walks over and slaps his face and leaves.

You can see the slap around 0:37 in the film’s trailer:



